# How to get both null and 0 for decimal in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to get retrieve both null and 0.00 for sugar_per_serving into api from the database. The datatype is BigDecimal. Now I put blank in the database, but on the api it is showing 0. Is there a way to change 0 to null? Below is my code:

```
WeightManagement.java
public BigDecimal sugar_per_serving;

public BigDecimal getSugar_per_serving() {
    return sugar_per_serving;
}

public void setSugar_per_serving(BigDecimal sugar_per_serving) {
    this.sugar_per_serving = sugar_per_serving;
}

PortalDBImpl.java
food.sugar_per_serving=rs.getBigDecimal("sugar_per_serving");
```

Comment: What is "blank in the database"? From the docs: `if the value is SQL NULL, the value returned is null in the Java programming language.`. Either you don't have a NULL, or the driver doesn't adhere to the spec (or you're converting nulls to zeroes somewhere else).

Comment: You can't get both `null` and `0.0` at the same time. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change only for select:

```
public BigDecimal getSugar_per_serving() {
    return sugar_per_serving == null ? 0 : sugar_per_serving;
}
```

Change if you need for update/insert:

```
public void setSugar_per_serving(BigDecimal sugar_per_serving) {
    this.sugar_per_serving = sugar_per_serving == null ? 0 : sugar_per_serving;
}
```